# Send Nth line of text to Nth address in the list

Tags: shell, shell-script, email

Suppose I have a file BOD which contains lines of text and a file ADDR which contains e-mail addresses.
How can I send the first line of BOD to the first address in ADDR, the second line of BODIES to the second line in ADDR, ... until the last line?

I know that you can send a mail in the shell using

```
TEXT | mail ADDRESS
```

but how can you repeat this task for each line?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your `BOD` and `ADDR` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following variables,

```
text_file="$1"
mail_file="$2"

lines_in_text=$( cat "$text_file" | wc -l )
lines_in_addr=$( cat "$mail_file" | wc -l )

line_num=1
```

You can write the following routine:

```
send_mail() {
    while [[ "$line_num" -le "$lines_in_text" ]]; do
        text_line=$( sed -n "${line_num}p" "$text_file" )
        mail_line=$( sed -n "${line_num}p" "$mail_file" )
        echo "$text_line" | mail "$mail_line"
        line_num=$(( line_num + 1 ))
    done
}

send_mail
```

Then you can use your script as follows:

```
./script BOD ADDR
```

---

**Edit:** An alternative way of doing this would be reading each of the text and address files into separate arrays, whereby every index contains a line of the respective file, as such:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a texts < "$1"
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a mails < "$2"

send_mail_alternate() {
    for (( i = 0; i < "${#texts[@]}"; i++ )); do
        echo "${texts[i]}" | mail "${mails[i]}"
    done
}

send_mail_alternate
```

Here, the two arrays created are `texts` and `mails`. `"${#texts[@]}"` represents the total number of lines in array `texts`, and each line can be accessed by `"${texts[i]}"` or `"${mails[i]}"`, where `i` starts from 0 moving up, containing line `i+1` of the specified file.

Comment: I believe that some of those quotes can be dropped, nevertheless this works fine!

Comment: The quotes are more a safety measure than a necessity when working with variables. But note, the script above assumes that you have equal or less lines of text than mail addresses. So if you have a text file that has more lines than your mail addresses, then you should work with `$lines_in_addr` in the while statement condition.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient as it reads both files N+1 times (where N is the number of lines - assuming the same number of lines for both files).

Comment: @don_crissti, I made an edit above to use arrays to store each files and work with the array instead of reading the file in every round of the loop.

Comment: That's better. There are other ways too, without "storing" the data (not even in arrays) but since the OP doesn't bother to post some input samples and specify if the two files have equal no. of lines (and what happens if that is not the case) I won't go into details.

Answer (score 0):

```
number=YOUR_NUMBER_OF_LINE
message=$(head -n ${number} file_wit_TEXT | tail -1)
address=$(head -n ${number} file_with_ADDRESSES | tail -1)
echo ${message} | mail ${address}
```